# Chrome 66 shows HTML code instead of rendering

Tags: google-chrome, html-rendering

I have a HTML file that renders correctly in Chrome 66 when the file extension is ".html", so I know that the code if fine.

However, the process that generates the code defaults to an extension of ".DAT" and there isn't a way to change it. Also, I tried associating ".DAT" with Chrome, but the page still shows code instead of rendering.

When I was using an older version of Chrome (50 something) it was rendering the pages properly. How can I get ".DAT" files to render correctly in my newer version?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behaviour today with one of our users.
Some DAT files with html coding are displayed as loose html code instead of being rendered.
If I open it in IE it works fine.

Comment: This is a good comment, but doesn't provide an answer so should not be posted as one.